# git: how can I easily tell if I'm in the middle of a rebase

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I'm writing a bash one-liner where I want to do something automatically every time I run `git rebase --continue` inside a `while [ true ]` loop. When it stops, if I'm still rebasing, I will do X, then I will ask rebase to continue again. Is there an easy easy to tell if I'm still rebasing? I tried with `if [ ! -f .git/REBASE_HEAD ]; then break; fi` but the file is still present after rebase is finished. I see that `.git/rebase-merge` is present while rebasing and gone after it's done. Can I use it as my tip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can see [how `git-prompt.sh` detects being in a rebase](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L428).

```
    if [ -d "$g/rebase-merge" ]; then
        if [ -f "$g/rebase-merge/interactive" ]; then
            r="|REBASE-i"
        else
            r="|REBASE-m"
        fi
    else
        if [ -d "$g/rebase-apply" ]; then
            if [ -f "$g/rebase-apply/rebasing" ]; then
                r="|REBASE"
            elif [ -f "$g/rebase-apply/applying" ]; then
                r="|AM"
            else
                r="|AM/REBASE"
            fi
        elif [ -f "$g/MERGE_HEAD" ]; then
            r="|MERGING"
        elif __git_sequencer_status; then
            :
        elif [ -f "$g/BISECT_LOG" ]; then
            r="|BISECTING"
        fi
```

And there are additional statuses in [`__git_sequencer_status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L293).

Because the Git directory is not always `.git`, the script uses `git rev-parse --git-dir` to get the git directory (`$g` above). Then you can see from the above which directories and files inside correspond to what actions.

Boiling that down, you're looking for one of two directories.

- `$g/rebase-merge`
- `$g/rebase-apply`

Comment: The `git status` command really should have a plumbing counterpart (or options to do the plumbing counterpart) so that you could get this information without peering into the Git directory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that works. Look [how `git-prompt.sh` does it](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8679ef24ed64018bb62170c43ce73e0261c0600a/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L428-L448) to set your `PS1`:

```
if [ -d "$g/rebase-merge" ]; then
    __git_eread "$g/rebase-merge/head-name" b
    __git_eread "$g/rebase-merge/msgnum" step
    __git_eread "$g/rebase-merge/end" total
    if [ -f "$g/rebase-merge/interactive" ]; then
        r="|REBASE-i"
    else
        r="|REBASE-m"
    fi
else
    if [ -d "$g/rebase-apply" ]; then
        __git_eread "$g/rebase-apply/next" step
        __git_eread "$g/rebase-apply/last" total
        if [ -f "$g/rebase-apply/rebasing" ]; then
            __git_eread "$g/rebase-apply/head-name" b
            r="|REBASE"
        elif [ -f "$g/rebase-apply/applying" ]; then
            r="|AM"
        else
            r="|AM/REBASE"
        fi
```

Comment: Your answer is pretty much what I was asking for but @Schwern provided more details that I should consider. I have upvoted yours, nevertheless.